# Mcrypt setup for Serpent 256bit key

Tags: encryption, mcrypt

I am trying to decrypt a sample file using mcrypt, encryption/decryption is confirmed to be working with Gringotts.

Gringotts used algorithms:

```
Encryption: Serpent
Block size: 128 bits
Key length: 256 bits
Hashing: RIPEMD 160
Compression: Zlib Best
```

Used mcrypt command:

> mcrypt -V -s 256 -z -a serpent -h ripemd160 -d sample.grg

With the error message:

```
The specified key size is too large for this algorithm.
```

I'm not sure what I am missing, any suggestions?